# How to find the next greater number and next lower number in an array

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

Initially, I have a value, lets say `100`.

Then I also have an array with elements like `[99, 101, 102, 103, 98, 95, 97]`

What I want, I want a new array to have a first element which is most nearer to the value `100`
That is `101` & `99` and then the next most nearer value is `102` & `98` and so on.

So the final array would be something like this `[99, 101, 98, 102, 97, 103, 95]`

So in php how could I solve this problem ?

Any specific algorithm for this problem ?

Comment: You could iterate through all elements of `[99, 101, 102, 103, 98, 95, 97]` and calculate a kind of a score: `abs(100-array[i])`. That score would represent how far is the element from the number 100. You would then sort the original array based on that score.

Comment: what if there are ```10,000``` records?

Comment: And what about the lower number. Because ```99``` & ```101``` are both at the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply collect numbers in an associative array with key as difference with 100. Later, you can do a [`ksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort them according to differences. This way, your sorting cost would be minimal on a lot of average cases.

```
<?php

$a = array(99, 95, 101, 102, 103, 98, 97, 110);

$number = 100;
$diff = [];

foreach($a as $ele){
    $diff[abs($number - $ele)][] = $ele;
}

ksort($diff,SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($diff);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/QPX1o

Comment: Can you please tell me the efficiency of this above code? For example, Lets say If I have more than 1000 elements in an array, how far it will work ?

Comment: @DanishTahir The time complexity of this code is `k log(k) + O(n)` where `k` is the number of unique differences and `n` is length of the array. On an array of size 1000, it should be fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`usort`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_usort.asp) in order to sort an array by a function that you are defining. As @Pedro Pinheiro mentioned in the comments you can to calculate score that represent how far is the element from 100 which is exactly what usort is getting.

So your code can be:

```php
<?php
function sort_100($a,$b)
{
if ($a==$b) return 0;
return (abs(100-($a))<abs(100-($b))?-1:1;
}

$a=array(99, 101, 102, 103, 98, 95, 97);
usort($a,"sort_100");
?>
```

Comment: This worked too !!! But I was unable to pass on variable in usort. As you may know 100 is variable.